# Java version in spring boot , docker and EC2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, amazon-ec2

- Spring boot version - 2.1.13.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
- Java compiler version - Jdk11
- AWS EC2 Java version - jdk7

I've started working on a microservice project. So the docker image of my service was compiled in Jdk11. When I try to download and run the container - it doesn't run. Now upon checking logs, I see - java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError
I'm using maven to build. Should I change the java version in pom.xml? I could not update the java version in the ec2. Please let me know how I can resolve this collision and go-ahead. I have many services and I'm trying to put it all in EC2.

Docker file: updated to Java 11

```
FROM openjdk:11.0-jdk-slim
VOLUME /tmp
COPY snapAppKey.jks snapAppKey.jks
COPY /target/SnapAppConfigServer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ConfigServer.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","ConfigServer.jar"]
```

EC2

```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/snapapp/config/api/SnapAppConfigServerApplication has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:93)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:46)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52)
```

Comment: As given, the issue `java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError` happens because of a higher JDK during compile time and lower JDK during runtime. To fix this, upgrade the runtime in your aws ec2 instance, based on the type of os distro you're using.

Comment: Can you replace that image file with the actual text content of your logs?  It's difficult to read, and impossible to search its contents.

Comment: @DavidMaze Docker file updated

Comment: If this is running in Docker, the JVM installed on the host (if any) doesn't matter and isn't considered at all.  But your Dockerfile says to use OpenJDK 8, and if the jar file was built using Java 11, that'd lead to the error you're reporting.

Comment: yeah the jar was built using Java 11. So it's because I've asked docker to build image using jdk8 and I'm trying to run it on 7. So what would you suggest, updating my ec2 to 8 as @QuickSilver mentioned below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Migrating your existing code from JDK11 to JDK8 will be more effort that the above simple operations.

change `openjdk:8-jdk-alpine` to `openjdk:11` in your Docker file

Comment: sudo yum install -y amazon-linux-extras

Comment: Have updated the question with output. No package amazon-linux-extras available.

Comment: @continuousLearner change openjdk:8-jdk-alpine to openjdk:11 in your Docker file

Comment: `$ docker build --tag=config-server --force-rm=true .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  35.57MB
Step 1/5 : FROM openjdk:openjdk:11
invalid reference format`

Comment: Updated to `FROM openjdk:openjdk:11`

Comment: can verify your Docker file on this site https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk

Comment: I have updated to Java 11 in docker but still gets the error. Please see the updated question

Comment: 55.0 = JDK11 and 52.0 = JDK8 looks like you EC2's JRE is still 1.8 and not 1.11

Comment: I did not have to upgrade Java 8 to Java 11 in EC2. Instead, just upgraded the JDK version of the Java for docker image to Java 11. Rebuilding it again made it work. Thanks a lot for the pointer